# python mocking: mock.patch.object gotchas

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I have been writing unit tests for over a year now, and have always used patch.object for pretty much everything (modules, classes, etc).

My coworker says that patch.object should never be used to patch an object in a module (i.e. `patch.object(socket, 'socket')`, instead you should always use `patch('socket.socket')`.

I much prefer the `patch.object` method, as it allows me to import modules and is more pythonic in my opinion. Is my coworker right?

Note: I have looked through the patch documentation and can't find any warnings on this subject. Isn't *everything* an object in python?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such requirement, and yes, everything is an object in Python.

It is nothing more than a style choice; do you import the module yourself or does `patch` take care of this for you? Because that's the only difference between the two approaches; either `patch()` imports the module, or you do.

For the code-under-test, I prefer `mock.patch()` to take care of this, as this ensures that the import takes place *as the test runs*. This ensures I get a test error state (test failure), rather than problems while loading the test. All other modules are fair game.

Comment: `patch` will automatically import it as long as it is on the python path.

Comment: @cloudformdesign: it was a rhetorical question. :-) I meant to say: ask yourself that question to determine what you would prefer. I added a reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: I decided to just look at the source code for mock and found it to be very simple and readable. I posted a longer answer below. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the mock source code, it really doesn't look like there is a difference.

To investigate I first looked at `def patch` and see that it does:

```
  getter, attribute = _get_target(target)
  return _patch(
     getter, attribute, new, spec, create,
     spec_set, autospec, new_callable, kwargs)
```

wheras patch.object does the same except: `getter = lambda: target`

Ok, so what does this `_get_target` do? It pretty much splits the string and calls `_importer` on the first part (making an object) and uses the string the same way as get_object.

`_importer` is a pretty simple mechanism to import from a module (using getattr for every "component"), and pretty clearly just makes an object as well.

So fundamentally, at the source level, there is not really any difference.

**Case Closed**

Answer (score -1):

These two are the same

```
@patch.object(provider.Provider, autospec=True)
def test_init(self, mock_provider):
    pass

@patch('provider.Provider', autospec=True)
def test_init(self, mock_provider):
    pass
```

Which one to choose?

If you already have the class imported, you can use patch.object, it is more readable.
If you have to import it just to patch it, then use a string instead.